# String repeating problem in shuffle in php

Tags: php, duplicates, shuffle

So i want a little team lottery system. All teams playing all team. No repeating!
So, i have got a code.

```
<?php
$array=array(
    "A1",
    "A2",
    "A3",
    "A4",
    "A5",
    "A6",
    "A7",
   );
 $teams=count($array);
 $played=array();
 for($i=0; $i<$teams; $i++) {
  for($j=0; $j<$teams; $j++) {
   if($i!=$j && !isset($played[$j][$i])) {
    $played[$i][$j]=true;
   }; 
  };
 };

 $matches=array();

 $a1=array_keys($played);
 for($i=0; $i<count($a1); $i++) {
  $a2=array_keys($played[$i]);
  for($j=0; $j<count($a2); $j++) {
   //$meccsek[]=($a1[$i]+1)."-".($a2[$j]+1)."\n";
   $matches[]= $array[$a1[$i]]." - ".$array[$a2[$j]];

  };
 };
shuffle($matches);
print('<pre>');
print_r($matches);
print('</pre>');
 ?>
```

Example results in array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A5 - A7
    [1] => A3 - A5
    [2] => A1 - A7
    [3] => A1 - A4
    [4] => A3 - A7
    [5] => A2 - A6
    [6] => A3 - A6
    [7] => A5 - A6
    [8] => A1 - A3
    [9] => A3 - A4
    [10] => A4 - A7
    [11] => A2 - A3
    [12] => A2 - A7
    [13] => A1 - A5
    [14] => A2 - A4
    [15] => A2 - A5
    [16] => A4 - A5
    [17] => A1 - A2
    [18] => A4 - A6
    [19] => A1 - A6
    [20] => A6 - A7
)
```

I haven'got idea how to terminate the duplicate first elements. I need some idea or short example how to do. Thx.

Comment: Elaborate. What is meant by duplicates? `A1 - A7` and `A7 - A1`?

Comment: [2] => **A1** - A7
  [3] => **A1** - A4

consecutive first object in string

Comment: Looks like they don't want a team playing consecutive games.

Comment: What do you mean by "I haven'got idea how to terminate the duplicate first elements"? They're not duplicates, the second team is different? Do you mean you don't want teams to play consecutively?

Comment: Sry.

So  i want terminate repeating consecutive first element.

BAD

    [2] => A1 - A7
    [3] => A1 - A4
    [4] => A3 - A7
    [5] => A2 - A6

Good for me

    [2] => A1 - A7 
    [4] => A3 - A7
    [5] => A2 - A6
    [3] => A1 - A4

Comment: So the current output is fine, you just want to order it to not have the first team in each row to appear consecutively in the array?

Comment: Exactly this is it!

Comment: That's not possible. Consider 4 teams. I see no arrangement for non collision matches.